# PHP laravel nested loop calculation performance

Tags: php, laravel, nested-loops

In my project I'm doing calculation for solar panel angle, and the details of calculation is down to every 6 minutes in a year for every angle between 1 degree to 90 degree.

So there will be nasty nested loop for each angle 90, than to for each month 12, than for each day of the month 30, and for each 6 minutes in a day (240 loops).

90 x 12 x 30 X 240 = 7.776.000

With that more than 7 million times calculation even in my localhost it takes full 20 seconds to finish. The problem arise when I upload my project to a hosting server, it always time out after 2-3 minutes unfinished process.

Do you guys have any suggestion to work around this kind a problem.

The code will be more or less like this:

```php
  for(i = 0; i < 90; i++){
    for(m = 0; m < 12; m++){
      for(d = 0; d < 30; d++){
        for(t = 0; t < 240; t++){
          //some math calculation like sin cos pow etc
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: On what does the calculation depend, the position of the object where the solar panels are, the sun? Could you elaborate a little bit more.

Comment: Maybe your calculation itself can be optimized.

Comment: For more performance you may want to write it in c++ and use `exec` to run it. Caching is also possible if the function is pure.

Comment: I'd recommend going with astro. You can clone the extension from https://github.com/derickr/astro

Comment: If you want to run it once use job and store the value in database to save common values. Else if you want to do it on run time I think it would be more optimised to do calculation for only current day or time.

Comment: the calculation depends on user input of altitude, longitude, and latitude. Then for each angle from 1 to 90 i must search the most optimum from every 6 minutes in a year.
I dont think caching is possible because, it depends on user input.

Comment: @Parsa_Gholipour After all I Have been tried. Ur answer is the best, and using exec and C really a solution. If u like u can post it as an answer and I'll check mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more performance you may want to write it in c++ and use exec to run it. Caching is also possible if the function is pure.